# Not valid point process model with interactions between marks and tessellation

Tags: r

A few days ago I was working on the analysis of point-level spatio-temporal data on a particular spatial domain. At some point, I tried to estimate a point process model that involved an interaction between a tessellation of the spatial domain and the categorial marks of the process.

The `ppm()` function returned a warning message saying: `Standard errors unavailable; variance-covariance matrix is singular. Model is not valid` and I can replicate the same behaviour using toy data (see below).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(spatstat))

set.seed(1)
X <- points <- rpoispp(50)
marks(X) <- sample(c("A", "B"), size = npoints(X), replace = TRUE) |> factor()
ts <- tess(xgrid = c(0, 0.5, 1), ygrid = c(0, 0.5, 1))

# ppm(X ~ 1) looks good
# ppm(X ~ ts) looks good
# ppm(X ~ marks) looks good
ppm(X ~ ts:marks)
#> Warning: Cannot compute variance; model is not valid
#> Nonstationary multitype Poisson process
#> Fitted to point pattern dataset 'X'
#> 
#> Possible marks: 'A' and 'B'
#> 
#> Log intensity:  ~ts:marks
#> 
#> Fitted trend coefficients:
#>                (Intercept) tsTile row 1, col 1:marksA 
#>               3.332205e+00              -3.364722e-01 
#> tsTile row 1, col 2:marksA tsTile row 2, col 1:marksA 
#>              -3.364722e-01              -3.364722e-01 
#> tsTile row 2, col 2:marksA tsTile row 1, col 1:marksB 
#>               1.335314e-01              -5.596158e-01 
#> tsTile row 1, col 2:marksB tsTile row 2, col 1:marksB 
#>              -5.596158e-01               4.994384e-13 
#> tsTile row 2, col 2:marksB 
#>                         NA 
#> 
#> Standard errors unavailable; variance-covariance matrix is singular
#> 
#> *** Model is not valid ***
#> *** Some coefficients are NA or Inf ***
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Unfortunately, I don't understand what's going on. Could you please tell me why this type of model is not valid?

Comment: I recommend to start reading about `variance-covariance matrix is singular`.

Comment: Aaaaaaah I made such a stupid mistake since I mixed up `:` and `*` notations when defining a formula... Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, the *model is not valid* problem is not related to `spatstat`. For example:

```r
y <- rnorm(15)
d1 <- factor(sample(c("A", "B"), size = 15, replace = TRUE))
d2 <- factor(sample(c("C", "D"), size = 15, replace = TRUE))
lm(y ~ d1:d2) |> summary()
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ d1:d2)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -2.1172 -0.6421  0.0000  0.5598  2.0714 
#> 
#> Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)   0.7071     0.5962   1.186    0.261
#> d1A:d2C      -0.4715     0.7474  -0.631    0.541
#> d1B:d2C      -0.8466     1.3332  -0.635    0.538
#> d1A:d2D      -0.2932     0.9107  -0.322    0.754
#> d1B:d2D           NA         NA      NA       NA
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.192 on 11 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.05134,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2074 
#> F-statistic: 0.1984 on 3 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.8953
```

In fact, the problem is that the model matrix generated by `~ d1:d2` is not full rank since the row-sums are always equal to 1.

```r
model.matrix(~ d1:d2) |> head()
#>   (Intercept) d1A:d2C d1B:d2C d1A:d2D d1B:d2D
#> 1           1       0       0       0       1
#> 2           1       1       0       0       0
#> 3           1       1       0       0       0
#> 4           1       1       0       0       0
#> 5           1       1       0       0       0
#> 6           1       0       0       1       0
```

The intended (at least for me) model can be estimated as follows

```r
lm(y ~ d1*d2) |> summary()
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ d1 * d2)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -2.1172 -0.6421  0.0000  0.5598  2.0714 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)   0.2356     0.4507   0.523    0.612
#> d1B          -0.3751     1.2748  -0.294    0.774
#> d2D           0.1784     0.8229   0.217    0.832
#> d1B:d2D       0.6682     1.5667   0.427    0.678
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.192 on 11 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.05134,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2074 
#> F-statistic: 0.1984 on 3 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.8953
```

where

```r
model.matrix(~ d1*d2) |> head()
#>   (Intercept) d1B d2D d1B:d2D
#> 1           1   1   1       1
#> 2           1   0   0       0
#> 3           1   0   0       0
#> 4           1   0   0       0
#> 5           1   0   0       0
#> 6           1   0   1       0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>